# One edge of stroke is bigger after change the left in Rect

Tags: android, android-paint

I try to create a stroke for my view and it work well if the left and top is 0. 
After I change the `left` rect, the left edge stroke is bigger than normal. 
Example, I set the `left` to 10

```
public class SimpleView  extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    RectF bodyRect = new RectF();
    ...

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        bodyRect = new RectF(10, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(20);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        canvas.drawRect(bodyRect,paint);
    }
}
```

**xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    android:background="#000">

    <...SimpleView
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="50dp"
        android:background="#f00" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the left stroke is bigger

[image]

**If** I use the

```
bodyRect = new RectF(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
```

[image]
the result look good

Any help would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I just find the solution. It is not bigger. Stroke by default don't display **FULL**
If I do like this, whole stroke can display

```
bodyRect = new RectF(10, 10, getWidth()-10, getHeight()-10); // 10 = strokeWidth/2
```

[image]